# How to separate a pointer to a field from a pointer to structure?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a structure which represents a map in a game:

```
struct smap {
    CHAR_INFO tile;
    Entity* entity;
} map[mapWidth * mapHeight];
```

To draw the map on the screen, I use the windows.h function `WriteConsoleOutputW()`. It takes a pointer to the CHAR_INFO array as one of the arguments, so i need to separate `tile` field from my structure, therefore I tried doing this:

```
CHAR_INFO* screen = &map->tile;
```

After that every second tile on my map was empty:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the classic AOS vs SOA conundrum. You made an array of structures (AOS) and now need a structure of arrays (SOA). It helps trying to imagine the memory layout differences between those two ways of organizing your map. `constexpr size_t MAP_SIZE = mapWidth * mapHeight; struct smap { CHAR_INFO tiles[MAP_SIZE]; Entity* entities[MAP_SIZE]; };` might be more handy for your use case compared to what you have.

Answer (score 1):

`WriteConsoleOutputW` expect a `CHAR_INFO` array, so probably you need to redesign your code:

```cpp
CHAR_INFO tiles[mapWidth * mapHeight];
Entity* entities[mapWidth * mapHeight];
```

In you code you pass an address to a first element, but it is wrong, because in the memory your table looks like this:

```
tile[0], entity[0], tile[1], entity[1], tile[2] ....
```

where it should be:

```
tile[0], tile[1], tile[2] ....
```

so `WriteConsoleOutputW` interprets entieties as the `CHAR_INFO`, which leads to undefined behavior